# How to update items in a component after state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build a todo list app.The items will be kept as state variables in App.js  and then this state variable are passed to another component (ItemDisplay) that will display it. But whenever I add an item to the state, the component ItemDisplay is not updating. What am I doing wrong?

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Textarea from './textArea';
import ItemDisplay from './itemDisplay';

function App() {

 const [items,setItems] =  useState([])

 const addText = (e,val)=>{
      // const tempval = items
      // setItems(tempval.push(val))
      // console.log(items)

      var newarr = items
      newarr.push(val)
      setItems(newarr)
     // console.log(items)
   // console.log(newarr)


 }


  return (
 
    <div className="container">


      <div className="heading">
        <h2>Todo list</h2>
      </div>
    <Textarea addText={addText}></Textarea>
    <ItemDisplay items={items}></ItemDisplay>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ItemDsiplay.js**

```
    const items = props.items
    //console.log(props.items)
    return (
        <div>
          {items.map(item=>(<p>item</p>))}

        </div>

      );
}
 
export default ItemDisplay;
```

**TextArea.js**

```
const Textarea = (props) => {

    const [todoVal,  setTodoval] = useState('')


    return ( 

        <div className="textportion">
            <input
            type="text"

            value = {todoVal}
            onChange={(e)=>setTodoval(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter the list here">
        
            </input>
            <button onClick={(e)=>{props.addText(e,todoVal)}}>Add</button>

        </div>

     );
}
 
export default Textarea;
```

Comment: The state in your Textarea component needs to be lifted up to the App.js component and then passed down to ItemDisplay.js

Comment: My immutable solution does not works ? if you create new array every time and not push to same array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a new array to trigger an update. Add an item like this: `setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, val])`. This will create a new array, copy the existing items, and add the new value at the end.

In addition, you should add a unique `key` prop to every item rendered by a loop so that React knows when to re-render. Like this: `{items.map(item => (<p key={item}>{item}</p>))}`

Answer (score 1):

In your ItemDisplay.js, you are assigning props.items to a variable. This happens only once. First of all for the component to update automatically you need to assign props.items to a state variable using useState hook. If you need to update the component every time props.items changes, you need to use the useEffect hook:

```
const [items,  setItems] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
 setItems(props.items)
}, [props.items])

return (
        <div>
          {items.map(item=>(<p>item</p>))}
        </div>

      );
```

Try this in your ItemDisplay.js component. Please import useState and useEffect hooks in the component.

### Update

Ya, you are right. It doesn't update because in your App.js you are assigning `var newarr = items`. This actually assigns a reference to the items array into newarr. Instead change it to `var newarr = [...items]`. This creates a copy of it.
Modified codes are as given below:

#### App.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Textarea from './TextArea';
import ItemDisplay from './ItemDisplay';

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  const addText = (e, val) => {
    var newarr = [...items]
    newarr.push(val)
    setItems(newarr)


  }

  return (

    <div className="container">
      <div className="heading">
        <h2>Todo list</h2>
      </div>
      <Textarea addText={addText}></Textarea>
      <ItemDisplay items={items}></ItemDisplay>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### ItemsDisplay.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function ItemDisplay(props) {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('updating')
        setItems(props.items)
    }, [props.items])

    return (
        <div>
            {items.map(item => (<p>{item}</p>))}
        </div>

    );
}

export default ItemDisplay
```

#### TextArea.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Textarea = (props) => {

    const [todoVal, setTodoval] = useState('')

    return (
        <div className="textportion">
            <input
                type="text"
                value={todoVal}
                onChange={(e) => setTodoval(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter the list here">
            </input>
            <button onClick={(e) => { props.addText(e, todoVal) }}>Add</button>
        </div>

    );
}

export default Textarea;
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Nope, Its not working. I tried using string instead of array and its working fine. but not with arrays.

Comment: I have updated the code and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you keep the array reference in app component so the child component would not update, update item array in immutable way

```
const addText = (e,val)=>{
      var newarr = newarr.concat([val])
      setItems(newarr)
 }
```